# Make F8 work as F8 on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

I would like to make F8 key on my MacBook Pro to work as an F8 key, not Play/Pause key, without having to press `fn` key at the same button.

How do I configure Mac OS X (Mavericks) to work that way?

Comment: just the F8 or all of the F keys

Comment: Either option would be good.

Comment: Your answer worked except for the terminal (example: `mc`).

Comment: @REACHUS: Are you sure you posted this command under an answer? ;) Besides, do you have enabled "Terminal -> Secure Keyboard Entry"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function can be set up by going to System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard and enabling Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**FunctionFlip**](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) which can 'flip' certain function keys instead of changing all keys.

> FunctionFlip individually controls your MacBook or MacBook Pro's function keys, turning special keys back to regular F-keys, or vice-versa.

[image: FunctionFlip]

> FunctionFlip's purpose is simply to disable the special features — rewind, play, mute, etc. — on the function keys. For example, if you "flip" F7, F8, and F9, those keys — only those keys — will revert back to normal F keys. Press the fn key with the special key to get the special function back. That is, the "special" and "normal" functions are flipped.

---

You can also use [**KeyRemap4MacBook**](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) with a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>F8 as Function</name>
    <identifier>F8asFunction</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_MUSIC_PLAY, KeyCode::F8</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F4, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_MUSIC_PLAY</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```